# Memory management for a large number of views in a scroll view?

Tags: android

I have a scenario where I'm coding a ScrollView which is intended to act as an "infinite scroll," dynamically adding more views to itself to grow the size as the user scrolls down (just like scrolling down your Facebook timeline). Each view that is added is a complex component containing a few TextViews, ImageViews, etc.

It should be no surprise that memory has quickly become an issue, especially once we reach the 50+ elements range. Before long, I'm getting serious OutOfMemoryErrors.

On iOS, I would simply use a UITableView, which solves the problem by removing views which are not on the screen and reusing their containers (eg, even with 100+ views in the table, you'll only actually have a handful ever being drawn).

Is there some similar technique or other good solution to accomplish this on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a pattern for efficient listview usage. There is great recording about that pattern from a [Google IO presentation done by Romain Guy from 2010](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) that is still valid. Otherwise it is also documented in all sorts of places - just [google for "android holder listview pattern"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=android%20listview%20io%20presentation)

Answer (score 0):

When list is having large amount of data then our application is pron to crash due to running out of app memory (Because of badly handled row view).
There are two way to resolve and manage list memory efficiently

**1** Use `converView`

> convertView - The old view to reuse, if possible. Note: You should check that this view is non-null and of an appropriate type before using. If it is not possible to convert this view to display the correct data, this method can create a new view.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View view;
if(convertView == null) {
    view = this.inflator.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
}
else {
    view = convertView;
}
// remaining implementation
return view;
}
```

[Read for more](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)

**2** Use `RecyclerView`

> A flexible view for providing a limited window into a large data set.

add the RecyclerView to a layout

```
//A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes 
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Once you have added a RecyclerView widget to your layout, obtain a handle to the object, connect it to a layout manager, and attach an adapter for the data to be displayed:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // specify an adapter (see also next example)
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
//... other code
}
```

The adapter provides access to the items in your data set, creates views for items, and replaces the content of some of the views with new data items when the original item is no longer visible. The following code example shows a simple implementation for a data set that consists of an array of strings displayed using TextView widgets:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private String[] mDataset;

// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView mTextView;
    public ViewHolder(TextView v) {
        super(v);
        mTextView = v;
    }
}

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    ...
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);

}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}
}
```

[Read for more](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#CardView)

`Hope this will help one and all.`